# How do I fetch data when data is added, deleted or edited in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, react-component

Can you please tell me how to fetch data when data is added, deleted, or edited in next js? I have used useEffect, used a state to run useEffect but that is not working properly in my case, only when I add data, the useEffect function is triggered. But in edit or delete, it's not. I have used multiple compnents. So, how can I achieve this? (without state triggering the useEffect function). Thanks in advance!

```js
const [added, setAdded] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  async function getTodos() {
    const todosCol = collection(db, "todos");
    const todoSnapshot = await getDocs(todosCol);
    const todoList = todoSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

    setTodos(todoList);
  }
  getTodos();
  console.log("Use effect ran!!!");
}, [added]);
```

Comment: How does the code know when data gets added, deleted, or edited?

Comment: I do this in the add function, setAdded(added + 1);

Comment: And what about deleted and edited data?

Comment: That's the problem mate, delete function is in another component :(

Comment: The structure of your code is very confusing. You don't want to define an async function inside of useEffect. That call should be in something like a `/lib/getTodos.js` that you load with `await` inside of `useEffect`. That might all eliminate some side effects.

Comment: @juliomalves so how can I solve this by keeping my delete function in another component?

Comment: I'd recommend you look into [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or other React state libraries to update state across components.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation needs refactoring.

The problem is mutable and immutable variables.
But if you want this code working, just store added as a property inside state so that React can track the changes.

something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({added: 0});
```

Comment: I don't want to use the state to trigger the useEffect function. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced. **You have to use Redux or any other state management tools for achieving this**. :)